# N-ое количество runtime permission

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

В Android 6 нужно получить разрешения на чтение контактов  и чтение\запись файлов. Проблема в том что  когда я пытаюсь  сделать запрос на один из видов `permission` то диалоговое окно появляеться но когда я хочу получить все сразу то ничего не происходит. Я делаю так:

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
}
```

Comment: Может их по очереди нужно запрашивать?

Comment: можно, возможно был еще проблема с тем что  одно из этих разрешений у меня уже было получено. В ответе добавлю код с которым 100% работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рабочий вариант для запроса сразу нескольких  разрешений:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(RegistrationActivity.this, permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("READ_CONTACTS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("WRITE_CONTACTS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegistrationActivity.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegistrationActivity.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);


            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All Permissions Granted
                // TODO: 9/13/16 can make what you want
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже есть, но может кому пригодится в будущем

1. Бэст Практис по запросу рантайм пермишнов [здесь](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)
2. Библиотечка для запроса пермишнов, может кому покажется так удобнее [здесь](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)